# How to create Group Summary in openfire server

Tags: plugins, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using openfire server with libary smack.
I want to create plugin which create new group.

what methode I should use/class?

I want to **Create New Group** in openfire -> User/Groups -> Group Summary
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create a new plugin for that. You could use already existing REST API plugin which allow you to create new Groups.

Link to the REST API documentation (speccialy to create a new group): https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-group

Link to Openfire plugins: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp